# Akka-http and converting Future[HttpResponse] to Future[String]

Tags: scala, akka-http

I am working with Akka HTTP, and I have a client that queries a URL. The code is something like this:

```
def f1(): Future[HttpResponse] =  { ... }
```

I want to write a `f2` function that takes the `HttpRespons`e but turns it into a `Future[String]` where the `String` is the body of the message. So I am looking for:

```
def f2(): Future[String] = f1().map(...)
```

I am unable to convert the get this to work correctly.

**Question #1**: This is more of a basic Scala question, I think. How would I convert this future? The best I can get is:

```
def f2:Future[String] = {
 f1().map (_.entity.toStrict(300.milli).map(_.data.utf8String))
}
```

which doesn't work since I end up with a `Future[Future[String]]`

**Question #2**: This is an akka-http question for my understanding.

does `f1().map(_.toStrict())`   imply   `f1().map(_.entity.toStrict())` ?

If so, how can I access the entity without having to call toStrict on it as well?

Comment: Use `flatMap` instead of `map` when the result of the function passed to `map` returns a `Future` itself.

Comment: Could you please explain why you want to convert it to a String and what you'll use it for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

// 1. You can use a for comprehension (with Option[Option[T]], Future[Future[T]], Try[Try[T]) or flatMap or .map { _ pipeTo self } (if in an actor).

```
val httpResponseF: Future[HttpResponse] = Future.successful(HttpResponse(entity = HttpEntity.Strict(ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`, data = ByteString("test"))))
val res: Future[String] = for {
  httpResponse <- httpResponseF
  entity       <- httpResponse.entity.toStrict(300.milli)
} yield {
  entity match {
    case HttpEntity.Strict(contentType, data) => data.utf8String
  }
}
assert(Await.result(res, 1.second) == "test")
```

// 2. They look different to me:
akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpResponse

```
def
toStrict(timeout: FiniteDuration)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext, fm: Materializer): Future[Self]
```

vs

//akka.http.javadsl.model.ResponseEntity

```
def
toStrict(timeoutMillis: Long, materializer: Materializer): CompletionStage[HttpEntity.Strict]
```

One uses implicits.

Here is one way to get a string as an http client.

```
object Example {
  import scala.concurrent.Future
  import akka.actor.ActorSystem
  import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
  import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
  import akka.stream.scaladsl.Sink
  import akka.stream.scaladsl.Source
  import akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling._
  import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
  import scala.util.{Try,Success,Failure}
  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val ec = system.dispatcher
  // construct a pool client flow with context type `Int`
  val poolClientFlow = Http().cachedHostConnectionPool[Int]("akka.io")
  val responseFuture: Future[String] =
    Source.single(HttpRequest(uri = "/") -> 1)
      .via(poolClientFlow)
      .mapAsync(1) { 
          case (Success(response), i) => Unmarshal(response.entity).to[String]
          case (Failure(e), i)        => Future.failed(e)
      }
      .runWith(Sink.head)

}
```

If there is a more specific type (more idiomatic if using Scala) you are trying to unmarshall to rather than string you can create a custom Unmarshaller using this Json one as a template: https://github.com/hseeberger/akka-http-json/blob/master/akka-http-json4s/src/main/scala/de/heikoseeberger/akkahttpjson4s/Json4sSupport.scala otherwise there is Unmarshallers.String http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.3/java/http/routing-dsl/marshalling.html#Unmarshalling

Sometimes checking the Spray mailing list and docs helps since it has been active longer even though there is a new way to do it in akka-http it at least provides a starting point.

Comment: Thanks sam. I'm a little confused, the for comprehension yields a Future[HttpEntity.Strict], not a Future[String] ?

Comment: @WillIAm updated to convert to string.  Sorry tested the example at the end, but not the first.

Answer (score 2):

For Q1:

If you get `Future[Future[_]]` where you need `Future[_]`, you should replace `map` with `flatMap`. The same applies to `Option` and collections.

So this looks correct:

```
def f1(): Future[HttpResponse]

def f2(): Future[String] = {
 f1().flatMap (_.entity.toStrict(300.milli).map(_.data.utf8String))
}
```

For Q2:

`HttpMessage.toStrict` does call `HttpEntity.toStrict` internally so they do the same thing. (Note that for some reason `HttpMessage.toStrict` is not exposed in Java interface).

Answer (score 0):

You could write f2() as such.

```
def f2[T] = f1.mapTo[T]
```